# JS POST update data taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy, user-meta

How can I call the value of each term with my js function? I need use a Array not just

```
`  useractivities=[];

          $('.user_activities').each(function(){
          useractivities.push( $(this).val() ) 
        }); `
```

? How?

Here is my code:

HTML VIEW:

```
<div class="multiselect">

<div id="user_activities_form">
       <label for="user_activities-randonnee">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user_activities[]" id="user_activities-randonnee" value="10028">
        RANDONNEE          </label><br>
       <label for="user_activities-vtt">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user_activities[]" id="user_activities-vtt" value="10029">
        VTT          </label><br>
          
</div>
```

JS CALL

```
  useractivities=[];
      $('.user_activities').each(function(){
      useractivities.push( $(this).val() ) 
    });  // <==HERE 
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action'            :   'wpestate_ajax_update_profile',
                'user_activities'         :   useractivities   
            },
            success: function (data) {

                $('#profile_message').empty().append('<div class="login-alert">' + data + '<div>');
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
            }
        });
```

UPDATE FUNCTION (**wpestate_ajax_update_profile**):

```
             $current_user   =   wp_get_current_user();
             $userID         =   $current_user->ID;
             $useractivities = get_terms($_POST['user_activities'], array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );

             
 foreach($useractivities as $useractivitie){
    $useractivitieID = $useractivitie->term_id;
    if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
                if(!isset($_POST['user_activities']))
                wp_set_object_terms($userID,$useractivitieID,'user_activities',false); 
                else 
                wp_set_object_terms($userID,$useractivitieID,'user_activities',true); 

    }   
 }
```

Comment: You're retrieving terms, but then you're saving post meta, not terms, you need to save terms, not post meta

Comment: @TomJNowell ok thanks! i need use wp_set_object_terms?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you issue your ID while you have to look for the "name" or "value".

```
if( isset( $_POST['user_activities-'.$useractivitie->slug] ) )
```

Change to:

```
if( isset( $_POST['user_activities'][$useractivitie] ) )
```

Comment: Thanks ! I go try this!

Comment: I have try 
`if(isset($_POST['user_activities']['10028'])) ` just for test but do nothing.
 Its ['name'] and ['value']  for $_POST?